# Is it possible to start iOS simulator for different devices (iphone4s, iphone6, pad2 etc) for same app, at the same time

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I want to start iOS simulator for different devices for same app. For example, I want to see my app side by side in all following devices;

- iphone4s
- iphone5
- iphone6

Is this possible?

My question is different from [Xcode6: Run two instances of the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446346/xcode6-run-two-instances-of-the-simulator) because I need to start simulator for different devices. That post does not answer different device types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode6: Run two instances of the simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446346/xcode6-run-two-instances-of-the-simulator)

Comment: Hi @QuentinHayot, thank you for your answer. I enhanced my question for pointing the difference between http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446346/xcode6-run-two-instances-of-the-simulator post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that but there is a limitation in it, you cant debug the log of all the devices simultaneously.
To do that first of all run the app on all the simulator on which you want to test your app, then in the command prompt, hit this link

> cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications

After that hit the below command, this will start new simulator whenever you hit this command.

> open -n iOS\ Simulator.app

Just press ok on Unable to boot device in current state: Booted Pop up.
After that go to hardware>>devices select the device in which you want to test the app, then manually launch the app in each device.
After this you will be able to test your app in all the simulators.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi @rajatp thank you for your answer. But I want something different.  I want to start simulator for a specific device. Something like following;

    startSimulator myApp.ipa iphone4s

Comment: I have mentioned it in my answer that after ignoring 'Unable to boot device in current state' pop up.From hardware>>devices chose the device in which you want to run the app and launch that app in simulator manually.

Comment: You mean there is no way to do it in command line. Is that right?

Comment: From command line you will only launch the similar simulator.But from devices you will chose the simulator and there is no harm in doing that.