# App do not run on second Simulator?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to run a app on multiple simulators. I did manage to run 2 simulators see link [Xcode6: Run two instances of the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446346/xcode6-run-two-instances-of-the-simulator).

I can run other apps on the two simulators. I did manage to run this app on the two simulators in the past.

For some reason when I try to run a second simulator there is a pause I can see IOS system log trying to open the it just closes.

I searched the IOS Log file found that both simulators have the same data (unhelpfull). I would appreciate it if someone can just point me in a direction where to start searching for the problem?

My Mac memory is fine do not have to few. The start file is also not have anything I can see that might cause this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was localisation that is why the add did not run on default english setting. The add worked correctly throw Xcode because the Sceme helped set the language.