# iOS simulator test multi-player games

Tags: ios, socket.io, sprite-kit, ios-simulator

I'm using iOS SpriteKit and Socket.io to create a simple multiplayer game, what is a elegant way to build and test it on multiple simulator (or actual iOS devices) and be able to see logs?

I see some post like this one [Xcode6: Run two instances of the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446346/xcode6-run-two-instances-of-the-simulator) which you can run two simulator, but I will have to run it on one simulator, stop it and start the second one. In this way it's making testing complicated and I'm not able to see logs of the first simulator.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode9 will support running multiple simulator at same time.

Answer (score 0):

The best methods to use would be to install it on a device (or multiple) and let them run without having to see the logs immediately. Then you could run the simulator or a device directly from Xcode.

If you want access to the logs afterwards, there are ways to get them from the devices. You could take a look at `https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1747/_index.html` for more resources.

Another method would be to copy the repository onto either a virtual machine or another Mac and run that at the same time as your computer. Then you could access both logs. Of course, it's not quite that quick to set up a virtual machine and not that common to just have a second Mac lying around.